# Calculate Full Period Basing Dates Selected by User on the Date Slicer

Tags: dax, powerbi-desktop

We need to create a dashboard with a date slicer and a TimeGranularity slicer.

The date slicer allows the user to choose which every date range they want.

The TimeGranularity slicer has the values like Day, Week, Fiscal Period, and etc.

To make it easier to explain. I reduce the model to only 4 tables: a fact table "FactTable", a date table "DateTable", a dim table "TimeGranularity" with flattened dates for different time granularities like Day, Week, Fiscal Period, a dim table "Location"

The TimeGranularity table connects to DateTable as many to one relationship.

What we need is, when the user select on the date slicer with a date range like 01-Jan-2017 to 05-May-2017 and the Fiscal Period level on the TimeGranularity slicer, the metric [Sales] should be able to pull/calculate the full fiscal periods that 01-Jan-2017 and 05-May-2017 fall in plus the fiscal periods in between.

Our DateTable has all the related columns that might be needed for this, like FiscalPeriodID, FiscalPeriodDays (how many days in each FP), FiscalPeriodDayNumber(day numbering in each FP), FiscalPeriodIndex (numbering of all FPs)

Currently the dax for [Sales} is:

[Sales]=Calculate(sum(FactTable[Sales]), TimeGranularity)

I would love to share the pbix file but don't know how to load it up here....

Thanks a lot in advance!